# Android 3.1 WebView overflow scroll - not rendering long list on scroll

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I've created an Android 3.1 Tablet app running on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 that renders an HTML5 app in a WebView using scrollable divs (`overflow-y:scroll`). A container scrollable div is set to a specific height and a child div list is dynamically created at load time.

In the Android 3.1 device's Browser, the scrollable container div seems to clip scrollable content of long lists, only refreshing the overflow div with content as the user scrolls the un-rendered content into view. However, in the **Android WebView**, the scrollable div does **not** refresh and show more content when the the clipped content is scrolled into view.

Though other posts have suggested iScroll, I've found it quite sluggish when multiple scrollable divs are required on one HTML page for my test device (Galaxy Tab 10.1).

Example App Code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    WebView mWebView;
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }
    ...
}
```

Example Overflow Div Page (`index.html`) - jQuery used to create random numbers for list:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  #overflow_container {background: #cecece; height:600px; overflow-y: scroll;}
  p {margin-left:20px;}
  ol {padding-top:0px;margin-top:0px;}
  ol li {line-height:48px;border-bottom:1px solid white;height:48px;}
  .container { color:#333;}
</style>
<script src="http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {

    $("#content_list").html("<ol></ol>");
    for(var i = 0; i< 100; i++) {
      $("#content_list ol").append("<li>" + (Math.random() * 1000) + "</li>");
    }
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Overflow Contents</h2>
  <p>Ordered List of Random Numbers inside a scrollable div <code>overflow-y:scroll</code></p>
  <div id="overflow_container">
    <div id="content_list">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Alfred,
Thanks for asking this.  We've had the same problem with a PhoneGap app on Android 3.2.
So far we've been able to get at least some improvement with the following:

```
"#TARGET touchmove": function() {
  var target = document.getElementById("TARGET");
  target.style.display="none";
  target.offsetHeight;
  target.style.display="block";
}
```

(You can reformat this into a jquery style and it should work, the key are the three target actions.  From all our testing of different combinations, this seems to be the only one that works.)

This article seems to best explain what's going on.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19827#hc16

We've yet to complete our solution as scrolling momentum scrolls too far after our touchmove event fires.  Seems so far like upgrading to 4.1 may be a good option, when possible of course.  In other cases we're looking into these options:

- Disabling scroll momentum, which we hope will allow the above solution to be a decent UX.
- preventing default on touchmove and handling the scroll action ourselves, with the intention of getting the touchend to fire and then attaching the same function to touchend.